# Ant with Hudson

Tags: java, svn, ant, hudson

I have problem in running the Job in Hudson. I have configured the Hudson with the ANT_HOME with the path of the ant and JDK as well with the relative path.
And I created a New Job, where I setup the SVN path and rest of the things.
My build.xml of the project is in Project root Folder/build/build.xml

And them I have added the build.xml in the Linux. Which is like this.

```
<project name="Test Job" default="build">
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${basedir}/svn/_build"/>
        <delete dir="${basedir}/build"/>
    </target>
    <target name="prepare">
        <mkdir dir="${basedir}/svn/_build/logs"/>
        <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/logs"/>
        <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/docs"/>
    </target>
    <target name="build"
            depends="clean,prepare"/>
</project>
```

Note : My I set my job name  as usercentral.

Then I tried build now on Hudson. It is giving me the below error.

```
FATAL: command execution failed.Maybe you need to configure the job to choose one of your Ant installations?
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ant" (in directory "/root/.hudson/jobs/userCentral/workspace/branches/branches/build"): java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.(Proc.java:192)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.(Proc.java:164)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:638)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:273)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:280)
    at hudson.tasks.Ant.perform(Ant.java:216)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:603)
    at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.build(Build.java:172)
    at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.doRun(Build.java:137)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:417)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1362)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:145)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:148)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:65)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
    ... 15 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

Can any one please help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Append `$ANT_HOME/bin` to your existing `PATH` in order for Hudson to be able to look for the ant command... or at least, that's how I fixed my same exact problem.

Comment: Yes, I have added that to the path, but still I am facing the issue

Comment: Did you try logging off and then log back in?

Comment: When you go "Manage Hudson" -> "System Information"... do the PATH and ANT_HOME point to the right things?

Comment: If that didn't work for you, you can use Hudson' ANT by going to "Configure System" then "Add Ant" under "ANT Installations"

Comment: Yes You are right, Thank you for the Help. I solved the problem. I looked into the Env variables there it is set as ANT_HOME <PATH TO ANT>/bin. So is the reason it failed, now it is working fine, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Give hudson the absolute path to your ant installation. You can do this in the configs. Then just use this ant installation in your builds. You won't have to give an ANT_HOME.

Comment: Surprisingly, in Jenkins 1.417 there is no way to specify named ant installation in build. It was in 1.413, but disappeared from project settings in 1.417

Answer (score 1):

First, I told Hudson to use some version of Ant that it automatically installed and give that version of Ant a name. (From the Ant part of the Manage Hudson->Configure System page)

Second, I told the new project which named Ant to use.  (From the Invoke Ant part of the project configuration"

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it could be a permissions issue. Does the hudson user have access to the directory path for all the relevant files and directories?

Comment: It has all the personalization "-rwx"