# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ant"

Tags: java, ant, build, hudson, jobs

I'm running a Job in Hudson.
I build this job from a Hudson Master Server but the job is built in a Hudson Linux Node.
This is the result:

```
Started by user builder
Building remotely on Linux-Node
Updating http: // Server/branches revision: 17-may-2013 16:01:46 depth:infinity ignoreExternals: false
At revision 529
Updating http: // Server/branches revision: 17-may-2013 16:01:46 depth:infinity ignoreExternals: false
At revision 529
no change for http: // Server/branches since the previous build
no change for http: // Server/branches since the previous build
No emails were triggered.
[bt] $ ant -file build.xml -DSUBSYSTEM=ALL -DTARGET=makeBuild -DCRLIST= -DOWNER= -DbuildTool.patch.release=$RELEASE -DbuildTool.system=$SYSTEM -DbuildTool.patch.type=$PATCH_TYPE -DbuildTool.subsystem=ALL -DbuildTool.buildRules=pkgBuild -DbuildTool.dynamicView=$WORKSPACE/ALL -DbuildTool.compilationRules=compile -DbuildTool.patch.name=$PATCH_NAME makeBuild
FATAL: command execution failed.Maybe you need to configure the job to choose one of your Ant installations?
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ant" (in directory "/hudson/buildTool/src/bt"): error=2, No existe el fichero o el directorio
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:192)
at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:164)
at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:639)
at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:274)
at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLaunchCallable.call(Launcher.java:794)
at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLaunchCallable.call(Launcher.java:768)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:114)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:283)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No existe el fichero o el directorio
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1021)
... 15 more
```

Do you know something about this issue?

Thanks and Regards

Comment: of course, Ant is installed and is in classpath?

Comment: did you check this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092479/ant-with-hudson

Comment: Yes fGo I read that but I don't find the solution. Ant is installed here: /usr/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.2/  and the $PATH is: /usr/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin

Answer (score 3):

May be you have selected default Ant Version in Project Configuration. You should have to select specific ant version in the drop down. 
Found at http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/Jenkins.html

Answer (score 2):

It is a safer practice to refer  executables with absolute path.  Instead of ant, refer it with `${ANT_HOME}/bin/ant`.  Ensure the variable is defined appropriately..